# Get details of Image selected from <apex:inputFile> Salesforce1

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, visualforce

I want to get the details of the uploaded image.

To choose the image, I am using following code in Visualforce Page:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="lbl">Image</label>
<apex:inputFile value="{!att.Body}" fileName="{!att.Name}" contentType="{!att.ContentType}"/>
</div>
```

I want to get Location info and created date of the image.

The below kind of `exif` data:

[image: Image Details]

Comment: You could put the image inline for quicker understanding.

Comment: It says atleast 10 reputation to upload image

Comment: I understand. I updated for you.